# Create Azure SSO Application using the Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to create an Azure SSO application using the graph API (no console).

I am able to create an application using:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-applications?view=graph-rest-beta

What I am having trouble with figuring out how to do using the graph API is the `Set up Single Sign-On with SAML` step. I want to be able to set the `Identifier (Entity ID)` and `Reply URL (Assertion Consumer Service URL)` of the `Basic SAML Configuration` section.

Can someone explain which Graph API I should be using for this?